# How to to add values from a file into an array using split?

Tags: java, string, file, split, bufferedreader

I have the following code:

```
BufferedReader metaRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(metaFile));
String metaLine = "";
String [] metaData = new String [100000];

while ((metaLine = metaRead.readLine()) != null){
    metaData = metaLine.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < metaData.length; i++)
        System.out.println(metaData[0]);
}
```

This is what's in the file:

```
testTable2  Name    java.lang.Integer   TRUE    test
testTable2  age     java.lang.String    FALSE   test
testTable2  ID      java.lang.Integer   FALSE   test
```

I want the array to have at `metaData[0]` `testTable2`, `metaData[1]` would be `Name`, but when I run it at `0` I get `testtable2testtable2testtable2`, and at `1` I'd get `NameageID` and `OutOfBoundsException`.

Any ideas what to do in order to get the result I want?

Answer (score 3):

Just print `metaData[i]` instead of `metaData[0]` and split each string by `"[ ]+"` (that means *"1 or more spaces"*):

```
metaData = metaLine.split("[ ]+");
```

As a result, you will get the following arrays:

```
[testTable2, Name, java.lang.Integer, TRUE, test]
[testTable2, age, java.lang.String, FALSE, test]
[testTable2, ID, java.lang.Integer, FALSE, test]
```

---

The code snippet to the preceding output results:

```
while ((metaLine = metaRead.readLine()) != null) {
    metaData = metaLine.split("[ ]+");
    for (int i = 0; i < metaData.length; i++)
        System.out.print(metaData[i] + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

---

Also, I've written your task by using Java 8 and Stream API:

```
List<String> collect = metaRead
            .lines()
            .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("[ ]+")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

And, finally, there is the most straight-forward way:

```
final int LINES, WORDS;
String[] metaData = new String[LINES = 5 * (WORDS = 3)]; // I don't like it

int i = 0;
while ((metaLine = metaRead.readLine()) != null) {
    for (String s : metaLine.split("[ ]+")) metaData[i++] = s;
}
```

Comment: No no, even then, when i try to access metaDta[0] it returns testtable2testtable2testtable2, it's supposed to be testtable2 once. So later I use for example

if (metaData[0] == "tableTest2"){
//do sth
}

Comment: did you know that strings are compared by `equals`, not `==`?

Comment: @OmarFayez, and why do you split by `,` if the file doesn't contain any `,`?

Comment: .equals sorry, doing multiple things at once and mistyped that. I did what you wrote, and went to print out the length is 1 and not 3. Also what I want is not to have 3 arrays with lines, I want 15 array cells with each cell has its corresponding value.

Comment: @OmarFayez, using array for those purposes isn't the best way, since you don't know its size exactly (`new String [100000]` is not an option)

Comment: @OmarFayez, I suggest considering `List` instead of an array and `add` there the values from the array. Or use my solution on Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Correct your code following line inside the for loop,

```
System.out.println(metaData[0]);
```

As

```
System.out.println(metaData[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although my answer may not fit completely with your question. But as i can see, your file format is TSV or CSV.
May be you should consider using **[OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)**
for your problem.

The library will handle reading, splitting process for you.